# withRouter with react-redux connect causing error with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I was fixing a bug in react-router-dom where i need to wrap connect with **withRouter**, i fixed the problem with this solution, but right now i have a problem with typescript, I'm getting this error.

[image]

Here is the code section where the problem is happening

[image]

And here my whole component file

```
import * as React from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
    import { pageHeaderHeight } from '../../utils/theme'
    import { closeDrawerMenu, openDrawerMenu } from '../../redux/ActionCreators/DialogActions'
    import PageHeaderLogo from './PageHeaderLogo/pageHeaderLogo'
    import SearchInput from './SearchInput'
    import DrawerMenuItem from '../DrawerMenu/DrawerMenuItem'
    import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
    import {
        RootReducerInterface,
        OpenDrawerInterface,
        CloseDrawerInterface,
    } from '../../utils/interfaces'
    
    const PageHeader: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    
        return (
            <AppBar position='fixed' style={ appBarStyle } elevation={1}>
                <Toolbar style={ toolbarStyle }>
                    <PageHeaderLogo/>
                    <SearchInput/>
                    <div style={menuOptions}>
                        <DrawerMenuItem route='/tutorial'/>
                        <DrawerMenuItem route='/partners'/>
                        <DrawerMenuItem route='/register'/>
                        <DrawerMenuItem route='/login'/>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state: RootReducerInterface) => ({
        drawerIsOpen: state.DialogReducer.drawerIsOpen,
    })
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => 
        bindActionCreators({ openDrawerMenu, closeDrawerMenu }, dispatch)
    
    export default withRouter(connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(PageHeader))
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// STYLES ////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const appBarStyle = {
        padding: '0 10px',
        height: pageHeaderHeight,
        background: '#fff'
    }
    const toolbarStyle = {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        padding: 0,
    }
    const menuOptions = {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirections: 'row',
        width: '50%',
    }
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////// INTERFACES //////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    interface OwnState {}
    
    interface OwnProps {}
    
    interface StateProps {
        drawerIsOpen: boolean
    }
    
    interface DispatchProps {
        openDrawerMenu: OpenDrawerInterface
        closeDrawerMenu: CloseDrawerInterface
    }
    
    type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps
    type State = OwnState
```

I just picked this project and I have no experience with typescript, I don't know what causes this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by including as any after (PageHeader), if someone can give a further explanation that would be great

```
 export default withRouter(
                connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
                mapStateToProps,
                mapDispatchToProps
            )(PageHeader) as any)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today; I'm not sure if it's the exact same issue, since the error message isn't identical (although that might just be from version differences), but I found a solution that doesn't require `as any` on the return value of `connect`. It's still a bit frustrating though, as it requires that you always add a second parameter, even if you're not using it.

The function signature of `mapStateToProps` according to the [React Redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object) is `mapStateToProps?: (state, ownProps?) => Object`, where the second parameter `ownProps` is optional. The `withRouter` HOC seems to insist that it is present, however. When I omit it, I get type checking errors, but when I include it, everything works fine. In other words, my `mapStateToProps` when using `withRouter` will look something like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, _: any) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.authentication.isLoggedIn,
    };
};
```